# MvcSiteMapProvider Visibility directives in annotation doesn't work when implementing custom visibility provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm configuring `MvcSiteMapProvider` with C# annotations and not through `XML`. I implemented a custom visibility provider based on the documentation. I derive my class from `FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider`:

```
public class CustomVisibilityProvider: FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider
{
    public override bool IsVisible(ISiteMapNode node, IDictionary<string, object> sourceMetadata)
    {
        if (node.Attributes.Keys.Contains("customVisibility"))
        {
            string customVisibility = (string)node.Attributes["customVisibility"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(customVisibility))
            {
                customVisibility = customVisibility.Trim();
                ...
                var criteria = ...
                return criteria && base.IsVisible(node, sourceMetadata);
            }
        }

        return base.IsVisible(node, sourceMetadata);
    }
}
```

My Controller's view:

```
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "My View", ParentKey = "ParentController", Key = "MyView", Order = 922, PreservedRouteParameters = "id", Attributes = @"{ ""Visibility"": ""SiteMapPathHelper,!*"" }")]
public ActionResult MyView(int? id)
{
    return ViewForEntity(id);
}
```

As we can see I didn't use my own `customVisibility` attribute with this view, but I'd like to use the standard `Visibility` attributes. This particular view shouldn't appear in the menu or elsewhere, except in the `SiteMap`.

The problem is that when this view's SiteMapNode is examined for visibility in the menu (a.k.a. `(string)sourceMetadata["HtmlHelper"] == "MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.SiteMapPathHelper"`), the `base.IsVisible(node, sourceMetadata)` returns `true`. I'd expect that the `FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider` will handle the `Visibility` attribute and return `false`, seeing that this view should only appear in the SiteMap.

As a workaround I currently implemented my own check:

```
    private bool checkDefaultVisibility(ISiteMapNode node, IDictionary<string, object> sourceMetadata)
    {
        bool defaultVisibility = sourceMetadata["HtmlHelper"] == null || !node.Attributes.Keys.Contains("Visibility");
        if (sourceMetadata["HtmlHelper"] != null && node.Attributes.Keys.Contains("Visibility"))
        {
            var htmlHelper = (string)sourceMetadata["HtmlHelper"];  // Example: "MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.SiteMapPathHelper"
            var helpersRules = ((string)node.Attributes["Visibility"]).Split(',');
            foreach(var helperRule in helpersRules)
            {
                if (helperRule != "!*" && htmlHelper.EndsWith("." + helperRule))
                {
                    defaultVisibility = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return defaultVisibility;
    }
```

This is a method of my custom visibility provider. I hate it, because it's not universal, only handles specific cases. At the same time I don't want to reinvent the wheel here. I want `Visibility` to be handled by the `MvcSiteMapProvider` internals. How to achieve that?

Comment: Off topic: Thanks to your question, I realized the [visibility provider documentation](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Advanced-Node-Visibility-with-ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider) was incomplete and have updated and improved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary keys are **case sensitive**. The reason why `FilteredSiteMapVisibilityProvider` is not returning `false` is because you have set an attribute named `Visibility` instead of the expected name `visibility`.

```
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "My View", ParentKey = "ParentController", Key = "MyView", Order = 922, PreservedRouteParameters = "id", Attributes = @"{ ""visibility"": ""SiteMapPathHelper,!*"" }")]
```

As far as making visibility "universal", that would be difficult to do since everyone has different visibility requirements. The purpose of visibility providers is to implement your own visibility requirements. `FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider` is about as generic as it can get, and if that doesn't meet your requirements you need to go custom.

Do note you can [override the default visibility provider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Advanced-Node-Visibility-with-ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider#overriding-the-default-visibility-provider) for specific nodes by setting the `VisibilityProvider` to the type string of the custom visibility provider class.

```
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "My View", ParentKey = "ParentController", Key = "MyView", Order = 922, PreservedRouteParameters = "id", VisibilityProvider = "MyNamespace.CustomVisibilityProvider, MyAssembly", Attributes = @"{ ""customVisibility"": ""foo"" }")]
```

If you need to use more than one visibility provider on the same node, it can be done using external DI and the [`CompositeSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider`](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/CompositeSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider.cs) as [shown here](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/355#issuecomment-55250326).

Note that you can inherit this class for use with the internal DI container if you need to - but for internal DI you need a default constructor, so the types that it uses internally must be hard-coded into the constructor. But you can create as many of these classes as you need for your entire visibility configuration.

```
using MvcSiteMapProvider;
using MvcSiteMapProvider.Reflection;

public class MyCompositeVisibilityProvider : CompositeSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider
{
    public MyCompositeVisibilityProvider()
        : base(
            typeof(MyCompositeVisibilityProvider).ShortAssemblyQualifiedName(), 

            // Note that the visibility providers are executed in
            // the order specified here, but execution stops when
            // the first visibility provider returns false.
            new FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider(),
            new TrimEmptyGroupingNodesVisibilityProvider(),
            new CustomVisibilityProvider()
        )
    { }
}
```

And then calling it by using:

```
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "My View", ParentKey = "ParentController", Key = "MyView", Order = 922, PreservedRouteParameters = "id", VisibilityProvider = "MyNamespace.MyCompositeVisibilityProvider, MyAssembly", Attributes = @"{ ""visibility"": ""SiteMapPathHelper,!*"", ""customVisibility"": ""foo"" }")]
```

Also note there are many other ways to control visibility including [security trimming](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Security-Trimming), customizing the templates (or creating new templates and specifying the templateName in the HTML helper explicitly) in the `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/` folder, or even creating [custom HTML helpers](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/363#issuecomment-58678912).

Comment: Cool, the `CompositeSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider` seems to provide the best separation of responsibility. I'll try it later.

Comment: I'm also using security trimming (role based) and customized the templates as well. Now my menu got so extensive lately that I'll have to look into caching for speedup.

Comment: It works, I'm using the composite provider along with my custom provider

Comment: BTW, originally I started with lower case visibility, but when the `base.IsVisible(node, sourceMetadata)` call into `FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider` returned `true` unexpectedly, I tried to switch to uppercase if that'd cure the problem. I still don't understand why that didn't work, but I like the composite provider better anyway.